# Viewing Advanced Property of network adapter like Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Is there a way to view Advanced Property of network adapter like Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty for Windows 2008 r2 ?

Comment: If you are looking for that functionality you could upgrade to powershell 4.0 on server 2008.

Comment: Upgrading to Powershell 4.0 does not appear to add the network adapter cmdlets (attempted on Windows 7). The documentation for [Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130901%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) is explicitly for Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to go with a `WmiObject Class`, something like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Format-List *
```

To configure the network adapater, you can find some information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-wmi-methods/).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with Windows Server 2008 for enabling/disabling JumboPackets. I have written this script for the same. It is working fine on my test VMs.

Please test this on any test machine before you use it in production.

```
$TargetKeys = Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

ForEach($TestKey In $TargetKeys)
{
    $KeyName = $TestKey.Name.Replace("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE","HKLM:")
    $SubKeys = Get-ChildItem -Path $KeyName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    ForEach($SubKey In $SubKeys)
    {
        If($SubKey -ne $null -or $SubKey -ne '')
        {
            $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
            $ItemKey = $SubKey.Name.Replace("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE","HKLM:")
            $PropNames = ForEach($PropName In (Get-ItemProperty -Path $ItemKey -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | GM -MemberType Properties -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select Name)) { $PropName.Name }
            If($PropNames -contains '*JumboPacket')
            {
                # Set to 9014 for enabling and 1514 for disabling
                Set-ItemProperty -Path $ItemKey -Name '*JumboPacket' -Value 9014 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                If($?)
                {
                    Write-Host "'Jumbo Packets' enabled successfully for Network card." -ForegroundColor Green
                }
                Else
                {
                    Write-Host "Error while enabling 'Jumbo Packets' for Network card." -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            }
            $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
        }
    }
}
```